# Powershell scripting - need to write and append a text file

Tags: powershell

I am by no means a powershell expert so my question will probably be very simple to most that are...
I currently run a powershell script everyday that moves any new .RTF files from one directory to another for all of our clients info.
However there are not always files to move and when that occurs I want to have the script create a text file for the first client this condition takes place and then append it for each each client thereafter.
I have tried several ways but cannot get it to work.

My current script for a single client is

```
$path = "\\XXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXXX\*.rtf" 
$Destination = "\\XXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXXX" 
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path)) 
{   
If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date)     
{       Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination    } }
```

then i run a master script that kicks off this script and the other 316 in succession....

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing each individual file in an `if` statement in a `ForEach (...)` loop, filter out those files initially:

```
$Path = \\...\*.rtf
$Destination = \\...\...
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
$FilesToCopy = (Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $LastWrite})
```

You now have an array of files in `$FilesToCopy` that should be processed; if that array is empty (has zero length), then you take whatever action you need to when there are no files to copy, otherwise you copy the files:

```
if ($FilesToCopy.Length -eq 0) {
    # Create the text file
} else {
    ForEach ($File in $FilesToCopy) {
        Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $Destination
    }
}
```

Note that @LotPings is correct in the comments; the `ForEach (...)` loop in my code above actually can be replaced by `$FilesToCopy | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination`, but I strongly recommend that you be familiar with the way the PowerShell pipeline works before making that change - it does not actually work the same way that the batch (`cmd.exe`) or Unix/Linux (`sh/csh/bash/etc.`) pipelines do.

Comment: Copy-Item accepts input from the pipeline so the Foreach is superfluous:  `$FilesToCopy|Copy-Item -Destination $Destination`

Comment: If the only variant between the various "clients" is the value of `$Path` and `$Destination`, then it might be worth looking into converting this script into an Advanced Function (see [`Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced)) and just calling the advanced function in a `ForEach` loop.

Comment: @LotPings - You are indeed correct, and I've updated the answer to reflect that, with due credit to you. I won't change the basic code, though, for the reason I gave in the edit.

Comment: do i need to give the variable $File a value or is this somehow set already automatically?

Comment: by the way ty for for the help!

Comment: @Dr.Fisher - `$File` is automatically set as part of the `ForEach (...)` processing. This is an "iterative construct", where each filename in the array `$FilesToCopy` is successively assigned to `$File`, and the `Copy-Item` command applied to the result.

Comment: great ty!  - I am getting ready to test all of this in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Have your commands worked out ,Get it in variable say $x and Then Pipe it to a Outfile
Something like This,

```
$x | Out-File -Append temp2.txt
```

Complete Code Should Add out to be

```
$path = 'your Path' 
$Destination = "Your destination" 
$x ="No files to copy for client1" 
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
 $FilesToCopy = (Get-ChildItem $path )| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $LastWrite} 

 if ($FilesToCopy.Length -eq 0) {
$x | Out-File -Append d:\creditdetails.txt 
  } 
  else { ForEach ($File in $FilesToCopy.FullName) {
   Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $Destination 
   }
}
```

Comment: so here is what I have and it is not moving the files or creating the .txt file  - I'm sure I have screwed something up...

Comment: $path = "\\...\...\...\...\....\audit pending\*.rtf"
$Destination = "\\...\...\UploadedFiles\...\...\CreditDetails"
$x ="No files to copy for client1"
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
$FilesToCopy = (Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $LastWrite}

if ($FilesToCopy.Length -eq 0) {
    # Create the text file
 x$ | Out-File -Append \\...\...\...\...\creditdetails.txt
} else {

Comment: ForEach ($File in $FilesToCopy) {
        Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $Destination
    }
}

Comment: Could u please explain what you want to achieve in brief

Comment: I have a group of files that get moved from one directory to another for 316 different clients everyday - the moves work fine in my current script but I do not get notified if there are no files to move and this has become very important.  In an effort to have it either move the files OR notify me in a txt file that there were no files to move, I have tried using this script to make it occur....

Comment: I see Jeff has given you the solution.Whats not working after that?

Comment: The final script that i posted in your comment section is not working at all - not moving the files or creating a txt file

Comment: To Improve upon this actually [Suggestion ,Create a log,For every execution catch the time when it was executed,Then Append the number of fles that this code copied.So it should look like [06/26/2017 01:00:10 am] 5 files were copied.[06/26/2017 01:00:20 am] 20 files were copied.[06/26/2017 01:00:10 am] 5 files were copied.

Comment: ty!!  i missed the final edit guys !   i appreciate the help and the time of execution suggestion!!